# Highcharts - Is there a way to disble styled mode for certain elements?

Tags: highcharts

We are using Highcharts styled mode in our project and very happy about it.
However, css object (inline styles) in certain situations better works for us.

For example, [`legend.itemStyle`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemStyle) property with {textOverflow: undefined, width: "dynamically calculated width"}

I'd like to know if there is a way to "overwrite" styled mode setting only for legend styles or give the inline style higher precedence for this particular situation.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/0r4nuzp9/)

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own custom style for certain elements.

`In styled mode, the legend items can be styled with the .highcharts-legend-item class.`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/css/legend/

API: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemStyle